# How to extract time from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

Just as we are able to extract the date from timestamps in Postgresql using `date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, I was wondering if there's a equivalent function to extract time. (formatted as hh:mm:ss)

I want to be able to compare a time value, stored in a column with the time datatype (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), to the current time just using an SQL query.

Any suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Doesn't just CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `current_time` or casting a timestamp to time: `current_timestamp::time`

e.g.

```
where the_time_column >= current_time - interval '6' hour
```

For details, see [Current Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in the Postgres manual